# SQL Server - Show client manager and senior manager

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table containing our client data and another our staff data.

How would I get the following query to show the Seniors Name instead of his ID?

I am using the following query.

```
SELECT Client.ID, ClientData.DueDate, Staff.Names, ClientData.Senior FROM Client
Join ClientData ON ClientData.ClientName = Client.ID
Join Staff ON Client.Manager = Staff.ID
```

Currently this exports the following

```
Client Code - 1234
Due Date - 12/04/19
Staff Name - James Rack
Senior Name - 685
```

How do I get it to show the Senior name instead of 685?

Comment: Sorry not sure how to make a list for the results

Comment: Add some sample table data for all involved tables, and its expected result - all as well formatted text.

Comment: You don't know the field name that contains the name you want to return?

Comment: Show us the structure of tables `Client`, `ClientData` & `Staff`.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the senior's information is also in the `Staff` table:

```
SELECT
    Client.ID
  , ClientData.DueDate
  , Staff.Names
  , ClientData.Senior 
  , Senior.Names as SeniorName
FROM Client
  inner Join ClientData 
    ON ClientData.ClientName = Client.ID
  inner Join Staff 
    ON Client.Manager = Staff.ID
  left join Staff as Senior
    on ClientData.Senior = Senior.Id
```

Using a `left join` in case `Senior` is nullable.